# Is there software or method that can automatically pause and resume screen recording, based on what is my current active window?

Tags: windows, automation, screen-recording

For example, pause when I switch to Chrome browser, but resume when I switch to Notepad.

OR

Resume in Notepad AND Visual Studio, otherwise, pause

Comment: [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org) might be able to do this (if you are using Windows)